# Prove the sum by vandermonde's formula?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$; Evaluate sum
$$
s_{n,r}=\sum_{k=r}^{n}(k)_r \binom{n}{k}(a)_k(b)_{n-k}
$$
where $(x)_y=x!/(x-y)!$

This is using Vandermonde's formula

$$
(x+y)_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(x)_k(y)_{n-k}
$$

not entirely sure, but it might also be using these identities, $(x)_{k+r}=(x)_k (x-k)_r$. So far i've gotten to this point..
rearranging factorials
$$
(k)_r\binom{n}{k}=(n)_r\binom{n-r}{k-r}
$$
substitute back into $s_{n,r}$ with $k'=k-r$
$$
s_{n,r}=(n)_r\sum_{k'=0}^{n-r}\binom{n-r}{k'}(a)_{k'}(b)_{n-k'}=(n)_r(a+b)_{n-r}=(n)_r(a+b)_n(a+b-n)_{-r}
$$
it looks like the solution is $(n)_r (a)_r (a+b-r)_{n-r}$, but i'm not sure how to get to here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Using what you have, 
$$\begin{align*}s_{n,r}&=\sum_{k=r}^{n}(k)_r \binom{n}{k}(a)_k(b)_{n-k}\\&=(n)_r\sum_{k=r}^{n} \binom{n-r}{k-r}(a)_k(b)_{n-k}\\&=(n)_r(a)_r\sum_{k=r}^{n} \binom{n-r}{k-r}(a-r)_{k-r}(b)_{(n-r)-(k-r)}.\end{align*}$$
Notice that $(a)_k=(a)_r(a-r)_{k-r}$ as you pointed out. Then use do the change of variable $\ell = k-r$ and use Vandermonde.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!